# What is the least complex way to iterate a LinkedList in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list, traversal

I have the simple task to print elements inside a LinkedList that has no duplicates with commas in between, but I have come up with two ways to do it and I'm unsure about how LinkedList iteration works so I don't know which way is best. I have some assumptions about both ways.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList<Integer> pres = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        pres.add(112);
        pres.add(114);
        pres.add(326);
        pres.add(433);
        pres.add(119);
// ---------------------------------- METHOD 1 ---------------------------------
        for (int i = 0; i < pres.size(); i++) {
            System.out.print(pres.get(i) + (i == pres.size() - 1 ? "" : ","));
        }

// ---------------------------------- METHOD 2 ---------------------------------
        for (int courseIndex : pres) {
            System.out.print(courseIndex + (courseIndex == pres.getLast() ? "" : ","));
        }
    }
```

For Method 1, I'm wondering if calling `pres.get(i)` in every iteration traverses the list from the beginning each time: (112) - (112 -> 114) - (112 -> 114 -> 326)...
Or does the pointer stay where it last was and just move to the next element?

For Method 2, it seems like the foreach loop avoids the possible problem that I'm assuming in Method 1, but I'm calling `getLast` on every iteration as well. Is it a doubly linked list? Is get last an O(1) operation? If not, is calling `getLast` on each iteration even worse than Method 1, since it traverses the list all the way down each time?

Comment: In method 1, if the subscript to be accessed is in the first half, it will be traversed from the beginning, and if it is in the second half, it will be traversed from the end.

Comment: LinkedList is a doubly linked list - getLast() is O(1), but method 2 is wrong - it fails if there is a duplicate of the last item. Are you familiar with Iterators? Hint: Look at AbstractCollection.toString() implementation: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/739769c8fc4b496f08a92225a12d07414537b6c0/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/AbstractCollection.java#L448

Comment: @Lesiak The problem I'm working on assumes there are no duplicates, adding that to the question now. Thanks for the warning

Answer (score 1):

```
String s = pres.stream()
    .map(Integer::toString)
    .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

By the way:

```
    List<Integer> pres = new LinkedList<>();
    Collections.addAll(pres,
        112, 114, 326, 433, 119);
```

or

```
    List<Integer> pres = List.of(112, 114, 326, 433, 119);
```

You then later might change to an other implementation:

```
    List<Integer> pres = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: @Miles this is the idiomatic Java way these days.  You'll get to streams later.

Comment: @MattTimmermans thanks. Indeed there are so many additions to java, it might be a bit overwhelming. Miles: But stream usage as above is very expressive. You could for instance have added `.sorted()` in the call chain to order the values.

Answer (score 0):

In a linked list, get-by-index (`get(i)`) is slow and can require iterating through much of the list if the index isn't near the ends.  You ask if it just moves "the pointer", but there is no such pointer.  Method 1 is therefore a bad idea.

Method 2 is the right idea.  The `for(var: list)` will use an iterator, which is exactly the kind of pointer you are talking about.

Checking the last element is bad form, though, even though it *is* a double-linked list.  You should do it something like this, instead of writing code that behaves oddly if the no-duplicates rule is broken:

```java
String sep = "";
for (int courseIndex : pres) {
    System.out.print(sep + courseIndex);
    sep = ",";
}
System.out.println();
```

Actually, I/O calls should usually be considered slow, so it's best to make just one per line:

```java
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
for (int courseIndex : pres) {
    if (buf.length() > 0) {
        buf.append(",");
    }
    buf.append(courseIndex);
}
System.out.println(buf.toString());
```